# Event uptime over a course of time

Tags: statistics

```
Event Trigger Check Interval: 3 minutes 
Trigger Chance of Event: 5% 
Event Length: 10 minutes
```

The above are the 3 variables in this problem. To give it a story, let's say I click a button every **3 minutes**, with the first click at minute 3 (not 0). On click, there is a **5% chance** a green light lights up. When the light goes green, it starts raining for the next **10 minutes**, after which point it stops raining. While it's raining, I'll still click the button every 3 minutes, and if the light goes green, the timer will reset to have the rain end 10 minutes from that point in time.

What's the average amount of time it'll rain in 3 hours?

---

I don't have a background in math or statistics (do in computer science), so I'm unsure how to tackle this problem. Any direction towards theorems or whatnot I can read up on would be helpful.

My gut instinct says I should start by figuring out how long it takes to reach a 50% chance that it has started raining, and consider that the average time it'll take to trigger the event.

```
0.95^n = 0.5
n = 13.5 trigger checks
13.5*3 minutes = 40.5 minutes
```

So on average, I can expect to wait 40.5 minutes for it to rain 10 minutes. This leads me to a poor man's solution of 10/40.5 or around 25% uptime of rain. In 3 hours, that's 44.44 minutes.

I believe this is "best case" "average" scenario, since it's thinking in averages, but without any overlap of the trigger happening, so the real answer will be lower than 25%.

How does this change if there's a wait period between when it starts to rain, and a second time it can rain again. For example, after it starts raining, it takes 45 minutes until I can start clicking the button again (which is 35 minutes after the rain has ended).

Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, of the $(180)$ minutes to be considered, you want $\sum_{i=1}^{180} f(i)$, where $f(i)$ is the probability of rain during the interval from the start of minute $(i)$ to the end of minute $(i)$.

Further, (again) if I understand correctly, the relevant trigger checks will occur at the **end** of $k$ minutes, where $k \in \{3,6,9, \cdots, 177\}.$

Also, for $1 \leq i \leq 3, f(i) = 0.$

In general, for any $i \geq 3, f(i)$ will depend on the number of pertinent trigger checks.  For any $i \geq 13$, this will specifically depend on the congruency class of $(i) \pmod{3}.$

For example, if $i = 25$ then $f(i)$ is affected by whether any of the **four** trigger checks at **the end of** $15, 18, 21,$ or $24$ minutes caused rain.  Alternatively, if $i = 26$ or $27$, then $f(i)$ is affected only by the **three** trigger checks at the end of $18, 21,$ or $24$ minutes.

---

However, while the above analysis illustrates the general considerations, the analysis is **premature**.  That is, individual attention must first be given to $f(i)$ for each $i \in \{4,5,6,\cdots, 12\}$.

Let $p = 0.05, q = 1-p.$
If a specific interval can be affected by $k$ trigger checks, then the chance of rain during that interval is $1 - q^k.$

For $i \in \{1,2,3\}, f(i) = 0.$ 
For $i \in \{4,5,6\}, f(i) = 1 - q.$ 
For $i \in \{7,8,9\}, f(i) = 1 - q^2.$ 
For $i \in \{10,11,12\}, f(i) = 1 - q^3.$

For $i \in \{13,14,15, \cdots, 180\}$, there are exactly $\frac{180 - 12}{3} = 56$ numbers that are congruent to $1 \pmod{3}.$

Therefore, the final computation is :

$(3 \times 0)$ 
$+ (3 \times [1 - q])$ 
$+ (3 \times [1 - q^2]$ 
$+ (3 \times [1 - q^3]$ 
$+ (56 \times [1 - q^4]$ 
$+ ([180 - 12 - 56] \times [1 - q^3]).$

**Note**
The above approach makes strong use of [linearity of expectation](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/).

Comment: Thank you very much! Your explanation was elaborated in such a way that even though I lack understanding of some of the terms/symbols, I could still follow along.

The added link to brilliant gives me more to read up on too, which is great. Thanks again! If there were a wait period before the rain could be started again, how would the above change? Would it be a completely different approach

Comment: @jcgzzc For a question similar to the one posted by your comment, it is probably best for you to make a new mathSE posting, with very explicit specifications for the question, and (again) including you showing your work directly in the question.